# Finding needle in haystack with NT script and store the fact it was found or not

Tags: batch-file

**NB:** This took me quite some time to figure out, so here goes a Q&A.

The following is a MWE of a script I am working on. The goal is from a category (argument 1 to the script) find out whether the category supports the subcategory `bar` (hardcoded in my call to `:FindNeedle`). Supported categories along with their subcategories are:

- **`foo`**: `foo`
- **`bar`**: `foo bar`
- **`baz`**: `foo bar baz`

Which means that categories `bar` and `baz` both support the subcategory `bar`. However, `foo` does not (i.e. the needle won't be found in that haystack).

```
@echo off
setlocal & pushd .
call :FindNeedle "%~1" bar
:: My real script shuttles a few variables out of the local scope
popd & endlocal & goto :EOF

:: Subroutine
:FindNeedle
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
:: Category
set REQ=%~1
:: Subcategory
set NEEDLE=%~2
:: This call will either end up setting the HAYSTACK variable
:: (see below) or not doing anything at all. It also suppresses
:: error output if the call "fails"
call :CHECK_%REQ% > NUL 2>&1
:: Jump over the "subroutines" used to set HAYSTACK
goto :END_CHECK
:CHECK_FOO
    set HAYSTACK=foo
    goto :EOF
:CHECK_BAR
    set HAYSTACK=foo bar
    goto :EOF
:CHECK_BAZ
    set HAYSTACK=foo bar baz
    goto :EOF
:END_CHECK
:: FOUND should hold the name of the NEEDLE if found or be empty
set FOUND=
:: This checks that we have a HAYSTACK to look in. It then shows
:: what the HAYSTACK looks like and iterates over its elements.
:: Echoing each element it then checks if an element matches the
:: NEEDLE we're looking for and calls :SetVar to avoid delayed
:: expansion woes and set FOUND
if not "%HAYSTACK%" == "" @(
  echo HAYSTACK ^= %HAYSTACK%
  for %%i in (%HAYSTACK%) do @(
    echo %%i
    if "%NEEDLE%" == "%%i" echo Matched %%i&call :SetVar FOUND %%i
  )
  if "%FOUND%" == "" @( echo ERROR: %NEEDLE% is not supported by %REQ%&endlocal&goto :EOF )
) else @(
  echo ERROR: Empty haystack
  endlocal & goto :EOF
)
echo Found: %FOUND%
:: This subroutine also normally would shuttle out variables
endlocal & goto :EOF

:: This subroutine is a trick to set a variable inside of a
:: for loop without using delayed expansion
:SetVar
set %~1=%~2&goto :EOF
```

Now the problem with the script is that it does not perform as expected. I called it `nested.cmd` and the following is sample output for a number of cases. The last two should yield no error, however.

```
>for %i in (boo foo bar baz) do @nested.cmd %i&echo ------
ERROR: Empty haystack
------
HAYSTACK = foo
foo
ERROR: bar is not supported by foo
------
HAYSTACK = foo bar
foo
bar
Matched bar
ERROR: bar is not supported by bar
------
HAYSTACK = foo bar baz
foo
bar
Matched bar
baz
ERROR: bar is not supported by baz
------
```

As is obvious from the output, `:SetVar` *will* get called. Yet we receive an error because `%FOUND%` is allegedly still(?) empty.

The expected output for the *last two* cases should be more along the lines of:

```
HAYSTACK = foo bar
foo
bar
Matched bar
Found: bar
------
HAYSTACK = foo bar baz
foo
bar
Matched bar
baz
Found: bar
------
```

A note

I know people tend to suggest "better" tools and so on when it comes to NT scripting. I appreciate some good Python or Powershell script, too ... but neither of these tools are on board on a vanilla Windows XP installation.

And while I am fully aware of the shortcomings of NT scripting compared to Bash, it still has its place and purpose.

---

My script is supposed to work on Windows XP (SP2) and later "only". So keep that in mind for an answer. The script makes use only of `cmd.exe` and tools built into Windows in a default installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to avoid delayed expansion, I missed one subtle fact about the behavior of scopes like the `if` and the `for`. The interpreter appears to read those not line by line but instead reads the whole scope at once.

So in my above case it would likely read:

```
if not "%HAYSTACK%" == "" @(
  echo HAYSTACK ^= %HAYSTACK%
  for %%i in (%HAYSTACK%) do @(
    echo %%i
    if "%NEEDLE%" == "%%i" echo Matched %%i&call :SetVar FOUND %%i
  )
  if "%FOUND%" == "" @( echo ERROR: %NEEDLE% is not supported by %REQ%&endlocal&goto :EOF )
) else @(
  echo ERROR: Empty haystack
  endlocal & goto :EOF
)
```

*and* evaluates the line:

```
if "%FOUND%" == "" @( echo ERROR: %NEEDLE% is not supported by %REQ%&endlocal&goto :EOF )
```

at *that* point. So me setting the `FOUND` variable using `:SetVar` makes no difference, because the `if "%FOUND%" == ""` was already expanded to `if "" == ""` by that point.

The underlying problem in fact is that when `FOUND` is empty, I exit the subroutine. So the code after the `if` never gets to run. We can test this hypothesis easily by setting the initial value of `FOUND` to `nope`:

```
set FOUND=nope
```

And indeed now the output for calling the script with the `foo` category shows `nope` as the found result (although it should show an error!), whereas the two other valid inputs correctly show subcategory `bar` as found.

Moving the line:

```
if "%FOUND%" == "" @( echo ERROR: %NEEDLE% is not supported by %REQ%&endlocal&goto :EOF )
```

right above the:

```
echo Found: %FOUND%
```

and thereby outside the `if` scope solves the issue. Expansion during the check now happens after `:SetVar` got called.

The finished script after the change looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal & pushd .
call :FindNeedle "%~1" bar
:: My real script shuttles a few variables out of the local scope
popd & endlocal & goto :EOF

:: Subroutine
:FindNeedle
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
:: Category
set REQ=%~1
:: Subcategory
set NEEDLE=%~2
:: This call will either end up setting the HAYSTACK variable
:: (see below) or not doing anything at all. It also suppresses
:: error output if the call "fails"
call :CHECK_%REQ% > NUL 2>&1
:: Jump over the "subroutines" used to set HAYSTACK
goto :END_CHECK
:CHECK_FOO
    set HAYSTACK=foo
    goto :EOF
:CHECK_BAR
    set HAYSTACK=foo bar
    goto :EOF
:CHECK_BAZ
    set HAYSTACK=foo bar baz
    goto :EOF
:END_CHECK
:: FOUND should hold the name of the NEEDLE if found or be empty
set FOUND=
:: This checks that we have a HAYSTACK to look in. It then shows
:: what the HAYSTACK looks like and iterates over its elements.
:: Echoing each element it then checks if an element matches the
:: NEEDLE we're looking for and calls :SetVar to avoid delayed
:: expansion woes and set FOUND
if not "%HAYSTACK%" == "" @(
  echo HAYSTACK ^= %HAYSTACK%
  for %%i in (%HAYSTACK%) do @(
    echo %%i
    if "%NEEDLE%" == "%%i" echo Matched %%i&call :SetVar FOUND %%i
  )
) else @(
  echo ERROR: Empty haystack
  endlocal & goto :EOF
)
if "%FOUND%" == "" @( echo ERROR: %NEEDLE% is not supported by %REQ%&endlocal&goto :EOF )
echo Found: %FOUND%
:: This subroutine also normally would shuttle out variables
endlocal & goto :EOF

:: This subroutine is a trick to set a variable inside of a
:: for loop without using delayed expansion
:SetVar
set %~1=%~2&goto :EOF
```